# Como acessar valores individualmente de objetos em array?

Tags: javascript, array, react-native, objetos

Estou tentando acessar alguns valores específicos de um objeto dentro de um array, oriundo de uma resposta de um método get usando axios.

Gostaria de acessar `id`, `dateTime`, `sensorData` etc de cada objeto do array separadamente, como por exemplo: `result[0].id`

Trecho do código:

```
const ShowSensorsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [ result, setResult ] = useState([]);
    const id = navigation.getParam('id');

    console.log(result[0].id);

    const getResult = async id => {
        const response = await searchApi.get(`/sensorData/${id}`);
        setResult(response.data);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getResult(id);
    }, []);
```

Amostra do result:

```
 Array []
    Array [
      Object {
        "sensorData01": "100.00000",
        "sensorData02": "101.00000",
        "sensorData03": "102.00000",
        "sensorData04": "103.00000",
        "dateTime": "2020-01-06T23:10:56Z",
        "id": 1,
        "idEvaluation": 1,
      },
      Object {
        "sensorData01": "110.00000",
        "sensorData02": "111.00000",
        "sensorData03": "112.00000",
        "sensorData04": "113.00000",
        "dateTime": "2020-01-06T23:11:16Z",
        "id": 2,
        "idEvaluation": 1,
      },
    ]
```

Comment: Esse código é de componente de classe ou de função ? `console.log(result)` dá o que ?

Comment: (Primeiramente sou iniciante)
Olá estou tentando fazer todo o código em componente de função sem uso de classe; Primeiro problema resolvi com ajuda, era um erro de assincronicidade em setar o resultado antes de receber a resposta pelo que entendi. O maior problema é acessar valores individuais dos objetos do array, tipo result[0].id (dateTime, sensorData, etc) apenas recebo um erro de **undefined is not an object**

Comment: Você faz isso utilizando map.
`<View>
{result.map(item => <Text>item.id</Text>)}
</View>`

Da para renderizar códigos javascript no jsx do react com {}. Se quiser pode criar um método para isto tbm.

da primeira vez que renderiza vazio, da segunda já renderiza a lista.

Comment: Muitíssimo Obrigado @LeandroSena, realmente utilizando map() pude criar um novo array para cada um dos quatro sensores que precisava:

   `const sensor01 = avaliacao.map((item) => item.dadosSensor01);
    const sensor02 = avaliacao.map((item) => item.dadosSensor02);
    const sensor03 = avaliacao.map((item) => item.dadosSensor03);
    const sensor04 = avaliacao.map((item) => item.dadosSensor04);`

Não sei se é a melhor prática, mas resolveu o problema, fico aberto a ideias se houver um jeito mais eficiente :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando map. 
`<View> {result.map(item => <Text>item.id</Text>)} </View>`
Da para renderizar códigos javascript no jsx do react com {}. Se quiser pode criar um método para isto tbm. 
Da primeira vez que renderizar, ela vai pegar a lista vazia, da segunda já renderiza a lista completa.

Vou criar um código com map baseado no seu resultado para ver se ajuda. Clique em "executar" para ver funcionando.

```js
const data = [
   {
    "sensorData01": "100.00000",
    "sensorData02": "101.00000",
    "sensorData03": "102.00000",
    "sensorData04": "103.00000",
    "dateTime": "2020-01-06T23:10:56Z",
    "id": 1,
    "idEvaluation": 1,
  },
  {
    "sensorData01": "110.00000",
    "sensorData02": "111.00000",
    "sensorData03": "112.00000",
    "sensorData04": "113.00000",
    "dateTime": "2020-01-06T23:11:16Z",
    "id": 2,
    "idEvaluation": 1,
  },
];

data.map( item => {
  console.log('item completo',item);
  console.log('sensorData01',item.sensorData01);
  console.log('sensorData02',item.sensorData02);
  console.log('sensorData03',item.sensorData03);
  console.log('sensorData04',item.sensorData04);
  console.log('dateTime',item.dateTime);
  console.log('-------------------------');
})
```